# When should you start pushing?

Tags: league-of-legends

At what point do you want to start pushing instead of just last hitting?  Is there a reason to do it at all after any towers are down?

Comment: Never stop last-hitting unless you're pushing. Only push  when... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/how-do-i-know-when-its-time-to-push

Comment: Well pushing some minion waves can have the advantage of denying some enemy gold tho

Comment: I think the question is worded badly and the OP is asking when to push. In which case it is actually a duplicate of the link @RavenDreamer posted. Of course I find that the answer to that link is inadequate as it only explains in term of global pushing rather than laning pushing.

Answer (score 4):

You never stop to try and last hit the minions, except when you're playing support; then you'll leave the last hitting to the carry you are with. But at times it's good to push minion waves to the enemy tower (either using your spells or starting to auto attack), since enemy towers can and will deny gold (and XP - only when your opponent isn't there) from your opponent. But you always have to look at the map when you are going to push, because overextending and dying to a gank is worse then letting your lane opponent farm.

Conversely, if the enemy is pushing his minions closer to your tower, you can start auto attacking the minions to get them down faster, but even while auto attacking you still need to watch minion hp so you can get the last hit.

Comment: +1 for the obvious we all forgot: don't last hit if you're tower's taking damage!

Answer (score 1):

Always last hit; you want the gold!  Even when pushing a lane, time your attacks so you get the last hit.

I think your question could be rephrased as "When to push, when not to push?"  In general, it's risky to push a lane because you're left in a vulnerable position.  The two biggest reasons I push early are to heal with lifesteal, or because I'm beating my opponents in lane.  It's risky, but an early tower break provides a nice boost for your team and frees you to float more.

Advantages to pushing:

- Tower damage
- Deny opponents exp/gold
- Healing with lifesteal

Disadvantages to pushing:

- Vulnerable position
- Uses resources

Some tips while pushing:

- Keep wards up in the river (you don't want to be ganked)
- Watch for MIAs
- Use care if an enemy champion has taunt.  Taunt + turret = pain

tl;dr:  Only push if healing via lifesteal or obviously winning, and then make sure you ward any potential gank spots.

Comment: I disagree with the comment of an early tower break is advantageous for everyone on your team. Sure everyone gets the gold, but an early tower break makes zoning you out of farming completely VERY easy. It's true you can float around more but floating to another lane means taking exp AND farm from these other lanes. Overall I think it results in less team gold gained. This of course is if the enemy team is smart and is actually zoning you once the tower is down. If they don't then my points become moot.

Comment: If you're floating and getting ganks, you're not stealing from other lanes.  You can still farm after a broken tower, but it does require more wards to watch the extra gank spots.  If you got an early tower break, you're not going to magically start getting zoned after it.

Comment: No but it is VERY easily for them to zone you since without the turret there to equalize the minion pushes, the minions will push down towards the enemy lane and you would need to enter a lot deeper into the enemy side to get farm. And as you already said, it will require a lot more map awareness and at least 3 wards to cover the areas where you will be ganked. And even then if someone is coming down the mid river and you are too far into the enemy side, you won't have enough time to get back towards your tower fast enough.

Comment: You should see the gank coming from the river; if you're not warding, that's a different problem.  If you can't farm your lane (you can, but for the sake of argument), go gank and break another tower or harass their jungle.

Comment: Also early tower breaks give you significant map control and open up the advantage to pressure the other two first towers if need be.

Comment: It's true, you have to go deeper, but in the same time they lose map control, this means that if they push alone they don't have the protection from their tower and you have more possibilities to gank too!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few times you should push.

1. when you are close to an enemy tower and the enemy needs to recall
2. when ad carry and last hitting goes well you want to be at their tower at around 8 to 9  minutes so you can recall and get your B.F sword
3. around 15 minutes if you are winning and you can push down the enemy tower safely

After the 15 minutes push you should go to mid to get that tower down. Otherwise you should try to just last hit.  Also if the enemy recalls and you're far away from their tower only last hit so they lose more experience.

Answer (score -1):

The only time you really should **JUST** be last-hitting is when your enemy clearly has no means of killing minions while you're laning. Some examples of this would be if you're up against two melee champions and you have two ranged. If you keep them off of the wave then stand between them and the wave combat and just deny them EXP and gold then thats a good time to last-hit. Also if your in a 2v1 lane (you being the 2) you should last hit until you can force the solo to recall then push. A great example of someone you should be last hitting against is Tryndamere. He is worthless early game in the waves so if you can keep him out of the combat by griefing him then you can last hit him out of a lot of gold and exp if you do it properly.

I don't know why these people are saying not to push and last hit. If you have the power and you're not putting the enemy at a disadtvantage by last-hitting then push. An enemy behind towers is a lot easier to deal with then an enemy in the brush or MIA. Keep your enemy pushed back to their tower and their tower will steal their gold. Towers mean everything in LoL, not worth your life, but taking enemy towers greatly decrease their map awareness and their map control.

Edit: Also I wasn't implying that if a minion is low on health you shouldn't focus it to get gold, I was implying you shouldnt JUST last hit minions except in these cases.If a minion clearly has low health then kill it, but that is just common sense.

Comment: I have quite a few problems with this answer. First: Always last hit minions, no matter what, unless someone else requires the kills. In the first paragraph, you are referring to "zoning" where you are able to distance your enemies from minions to prevent experience/gold. While zoning, you should continue last hitting minions. At times, it's much more effective to focus on minions rather than poking your enemy. Your second paragraph, in particular, is incorrect. An enemy behind a tower is harder to deal with, and you risk being ganked. Towers are not always top priority.

Comment: If you can't deal with an enemy pushed back to a tower how can you expect to deal with one out in your lane? If you are getting ganked because you are pushing then you don't have eyes and have 0 map awareness.

Comment: The optimal position IMO is right before your own turret but just before the turret is hitting enemy minions. You don't lose gold, can easily fall back to turret if ganked and can easily set up a gank on enemy. The way you play is super aggressive and unless you have a ward in the tri-bush and a ward at dragon simultaneously, you will be ganked. And this doesn't even take in account global ults.

Comment: A good ward at dragon is enough to see a gank coming down river.  Tri-bush is helpful, but not necessary since you can immediately fall back to your turret.

Comment: These comments are completely off-topic, I simply stated the possibilities of pushing a tower. Obviously being ganked is based on map awareness, but there's always a small window of time between wards that allows for a gank, as well as oracles and multiple other reasons.